# Read Spark Streaming from Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, databricks, kafka-consumer-api, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read some alpha vantage financial data as a spark dataframe from a Kafka topic on Databricks, when reading the messages using a consumer method, I find data that looks like :

```
Received message: {"From_Currency Code": "USD", "From_Currency Name": "United States Dollar", "To_Currency Code": "JPY", "To_Currency Name": "Japanese Yen", "Exchange Rate": "141.63600000", "Last Refreshed": "2023-07-21 15:46:04", "Time Zone": "UTC", "Bid Price": "141.62900000", "Ask Price": "141.63940000"}
```

But when I try to write Spark stream, I get "query returned no result" message

this is what I've tried :

```py
df = spark.readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", 'localhost:9092') \
    .option("subscribe", topic) \
    .load()


query = df.writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .queryName("fx") \
    .start()
```

I'm expecting to show dataframe lines in the cell result.

Comment: Do you really run Kafka on the cluster directly?

Comment: Edit your question to include how you setup Kafka, please

Answer (score 0):

There could be few issues here:

- most probably you don't run Kafka on each node of the cluster, so `localhost` is useless - you need to provide actual host name and other information
- If you want to see historical data, you need to add `.option("startingOffsets", "earliest")` to the `spark.readStream`
- the `df.writeStream.format("console")` outputs data to log files, so it's not visible. Use `display(df)` to see data in the notebook.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually we are using a single node cluster, hence the 'localhost' (this is just a proof of concept demo)